# How to get the correct XML page from Nexmo.com get-balance API by Java BufferedReader?

Tags: java, jsp

I tried to call a get-balance web/ RESTful API of Nexmo.com to get account's balance, but I received two kind of error response: (1)400 - page not found in GAE-Java runtme. (2)FileNotFoundException in Java SE runtime. How to get the correct XML page by Java BufferedReader?

```
String api =  "http://rest.nexmo.com/account/get-balance/{idkey}/{pwkey}";
URL url = new URL(api);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String strURL = "http://rest.nexmo.com/account/get-balance/";
    strURL += USERNAME + "/" + PASSWORD;
    GetMethod get = new GetMethod(strURL);
    get.addRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
    try {
        int result = httpclient.executeMethod(get);
        System.out.println("Response status code: " + result);
        String responseBodyAsString = get.getResponseBodyAsString();
        System.out.println("responseBodyAsString: " + responseBodyAsString);
    } finally {
        get.releaseConnection();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way you'd get a 404 is if the `key` or `secret` are missing:

`http://rest.nexmo.com/account/get-balance/[key]/[secret]`

Are you certain they're both being set?

(*Standard Disclaimer: I do a bit of Developer Evangelism for Nexmo.*)

Comment: hi, I am sure that my key and secret code both are correct, because I just send 10+ SMSs out.

Comment: I've tried, and can't get a 404 unless I leave out the credentials (or one of them). Perhaps [submit a request here](https://nexmo.zendesk.com/anonymous_requests/new) with the details.

Comment: Hi, I found out the Nexmo Java SDK. I will survey it first.(http://nexmo.com/download/nexmo-java-sdk-v1.3/html/com/nexmo/messaging/sdk/NexmoSmsClient.java.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only thing you have to do is add the "Accept" header to the request:

```
GetMethod get = new GetMethod("https://rest.nexmo.com/account/get-balance/{key}/{secret}");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

try {
    get.addRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml"); //OR "application/json"
    int status = client.executeMethod(get);
    ...
```

Hope it helps!!